# Proguard obfuscate package excluding classes extending/implementing some interface/class

Tags: java, proguard

I would like to obfuscate everything, but keep class names, because of dagger. Then I would like to obfuscate classes that implements some interface.

```
-keep class com.example.** { <init>(...); }
-keep,allowobfuscation class * implements com.example.util.SomeInterface
-keep,allowobfuscation class * extends com.example.data.SomeClass
```

First part keeping class names with obfuscated content works great. But classes name that implements SomeInterface or extends SomeClass are still visible.

Is it even possible?

Comment: I would like obfuscate classes that implements SomeInterface or extends SomeClass.

Comment: Do you mean the debugger? What is "dagger"?

Comment: I have a feeling that "-keep class com.example.** { <init>(...); }" matches any class below com.example package, and because of that even classes that additionally match the second and third rules are kept as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProGuard keeps the union of the classes/fields/methods that you specify in your directives. If a class matches your first directive, ProGuard keeps it, irrespective of any other directives. You probably want to refine the first line, based on some other criteria than just the class name.